# Add a 'Title' to the new OneNote page created using LogicApps connector?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Logic Apps to create a new page in my OneNote book whenever a new email comes from some particular DL. Now my query is how do I name my new page automatically as the OneNote connector in LogicApps doesn't provide that option?

I have tried changing the logic app json code but not able to find the correct logic where it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Page Content` is just HTML. You basically need to set the `head > title` for the title of the page.

[image]